# Background worker,Long Task or new thread for many executions in same time?

Tags: c#

Inside my application I'm using a timer. Inside timer every 1 second I'm running a long execution code(example to create a form and printing in many printers separately) while execute this code rest application freezes for 2 secs in every single action. What is the best method for running this without influence my main ui thread??Background worker,Long Task or new thread? Also new thread requires a non single core cpu?

Here are my examples.

Thread Examle:

```
new Thread(() => 
{
Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; 
/* run your code here */ 
Console.WriteLine("Hello, world"); 
}).Start();
```

Backgorundworker example:

```
BackgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
```

Task Example:

```
//Task should be run on other thread?
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
ThreadProcedure();
});
```

I'm new in c# and I whould like to learn more thing about my application's performance.

Also if there is another option more effective please let me now.

Here is an example from Background worker and timer within:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Code excecution has been completed!");
        timer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which options have you tried?

Comment: I'd use the background worker in combination with your timer so that you could still attempt to  kick off the background worker every n seconds, but within the timer method you can check to see if the background worker is still busy before attempting to kick it off again.

Comment: Threads are for fire-and-forget tasks where you don't expect any results back, don't care about errors or even if the task runs at all. If you want to get results or error messages returned you should use a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: For the low hanging question: No, creating a new thread does not require to have multiple cores. In fact, you probably have much more threads than cores already. As for the other part of the question... if the operation takes 2 seconds and the times ticks every 1 second, do you want multiple instances of the operation to run simultanously or do you want to only start a new operation if there is none running at the moment?

Comment: background worker doesnt make auto kick off  when my execution is  been
 completed? I just dont want to influence my main UI trhead when user is steal working insde the application with other  jobs

Comment: What is 'auto kick off'?

Comment: Please check my updated question and tell me if this approch is 
correct.Thank you very much

Comment: Use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx). NuGet "System.Reactive" to get the bits. Then you can do this: `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!"));`